# I'm making a checklist, is it possible to have both select and deselect with Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a checklist in my UITableView, and I also have a segue linked the cell. Is it possible to have select/deselect and a segue in the same cell. Because when I click the checkbox it selects and segues to another VC. Like a separate area of selection for both.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    [tableView .setEditing(true, animated: true)]
 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        NSLog("user selected", list)
   }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NSLog("user de-selected", list)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle(rawValue: 3)!
}
```

Comment: you can perfrm segue on some other button or accessory view of tableViewCell without affecting your selection / deselection

Comment: how can I have button that segues for every cell that is created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of that which I'm trying to say.
My storyboard looks like this.[image: Storyboard]
Here is code of `ViewController` class. 
From that I'm setting button's target method and tag of button.
 And from button's selector getting that tag and passing to `perfromSegue` and from that passing to `NextViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let index = sender.tag
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNextVC", sender: index)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToNextVC" {
            let index = sender as! Int
            let vc = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            vc.someValue = index
        }
    }
}
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myTableCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.lblTitle.text = "Row " + String(indexPath.row)
        cell.nextButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.nextButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is the code of `NextViewController`

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var someValue:Int!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblComingFrom: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        if someValue != nil {
            lblComingFrom.text = "I'm loaded via selecting row at index \(someValue!) "
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you...